# How can i use discord.Member in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def oyunC(ctx, player1 : discord.Member):
    sentences = ["Öldün","Yırttın","Öldün"
                 "Yırttın","Yırttın","Yırttın"
                 "Yırttın","Öldün","Yırttın"]
    picker = random.choice(sentences)

    await ctx.send(f"Sen: {picker}"+ player1.mention)
```

it gives me error:
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: player1 is a required argument that is missing.

*can you guys explain to me, for using in this situation?*

Comment: Please show how you are calling this function

Comment: You need to pass a member when invoking the command, an example would be: `;oyunC @person1`

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain how can i get nickname user who call this function in discord? 
Example; Sen: Öldün" @user_typed

Comment: @DoğukanKaluk f"Sen: {picker} {player1.mention}"

Answer (score 0):

Try player: discord.Member and You need to give a sort of info like their id.